# Yii - reacting to attribute model assignation

Tags: php, yii

I want to do the following in Yii:

```
When the attribute `a` in my model class `M` is set, do something.
```

AND tried using a setter like: `setA($value)` but it's not called since Yii `CActiveRecord` first detects if the attribute exists in database (and assigns it) and **if it does not exist in database** (i.e. it's not a table attribute) then a normal instance variable is looked up. The final fallback is calling a property accesor.

(**Edit** - I was wrong with resolution order: the lookup seems to be first to an instance variable, then to an attribute, and finally to an accessor - anyway, my problem is still the same since the accesor is resolved if no database field exists with that name)

[Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L154) it's shown the internal mechanics of __set (and a bit upper, the __get).

**Question**: How can I invert the order, at least for a certain attribute? This means: I actually WANT to capture the database field edition with a setter like `setA($value)`, performing the field assignation (i.e. the actual $this->a, however it should be done without falling in a stack overflow error) inside the `setA` method

Comment: Override the implementation of `YourModel::setAttribute` to behave the way you need? Might want to look at overloading `CModel::setAttributes` as well.

Comment: Put it as an answer, since it's a valid solution and found no better one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable approach would be to override `CActiveRecord::setAttribute` in your model class to behave the way you need it to:

```
class M extends CActiveRecord {
  ....
  public function setAttribute($name,$value) {
    if($name === 'a') {
      .. do something
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($name, $value);
  }
  ....
}
```